# Compose nested NavHostController navigates extra step back

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 screens: Main (M) and Settings (S) with their own `NavHostController`s .
The chain is next: **M - S - S1/S2**. When I do `M.popBackStack()` while on S1/S2, it navigates to M instead of needed S. But the hardware button **back** works well. So, I tried to use `navigateUp()` instead of `popBackStack()` and it worked correctly for some time until I reinstalled the app. How to fix the navigation back like its hardware companion (if possible, without using route/destination names)?

Answer (score 0):

So, I passed the root (Main) back action to the nested (Settings) `navGraph`:

```
val navigateBack: () -> Unit = { navController.popBackStack() }

val navActions = remember(navController) { SettingsNavActions(navController, navigateBack) }

class SettingsNavActions(navController: NavHostController, val navigateExit: () -> Unit) {
```

Also every screen (S1,S2) has its own `Scaffold` with a personal `navigateBack`.

---

There is an answer from a chatbot, but I didn't try it:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

val backCallback = remember {
    object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }
    }
}

DisposableEffect(backDispatcher) {
    backDispatcher.addCallback(backCallback)
    onDispose {
        backCallback.remove()
    }
}
```